# how to get selected dataRow from combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox which is bound to a dataset.  I'm trying to get the DataRow the text of the combobox represents, but I can't find it.  I've tried the following:

```
 private void cboItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable flexoItems = (cboItems.DataSource as DataTable);

        DataRow row = flexoItems.Rows.Find(cboItems.Text);

        //DataView view = new DataView(flexoItems);
        //DataRow row = flexoItems.Rows[view.Find(cboItems.Text)];

        lblItemDesc.Text = row["Description"].ToString();
        lblTotalQty.Text = row["QtyOnHand"].ToString();
    }
```

I feel like I'm just missing this.  How can I get the other values from the row of a combobox selection?

Comment: Well i think you just get the ID from combo box and pass it to database and get all data related to that ID. what you say?

Comment: The ID which is unique and when you pass that ID in database then you get only its data.

Comment: In flexoItems only these two column exists "Description" and "QtyOnHand"?

Comment: flexoItems contains "ItemNumber" (which is displayed in the combobox, and "Description" and "QtyOnHand".  I still don't understand what your suggesting with the ID.

Comment: Ok, so you want to get the whole data of selected Item correct?

Comment: Yes, I need the other information in the same row.

Comment: Ok,customize your database query which you are using to fill flexoItems then check your required items coming in datatable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am assuming you used data binding to populate the combo box.  In that case use the SelectedItem property of combo box.  It will probably contain a DataRowView, so you can use code like this.

```
DataRowView vrow = (DataRowView)cboItems.SelectedItem;
DataRow row = vrow.Row;
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get selected row from datacombo's datasource on VB .NET VB2010, VB2012.

This should work on VB 2010 and up if you have a form with a `datacombo` bound to a `DataBindingSource` in the form.

```
Dim dr As DataRowView = LOCAL_FORMBindingSource.Current
Dim r As DataSet.MY_TABLERow = CType(dr.Row, DataSet.MY_TABLERow)

MY_FIELDTextBox.Text = r.MY_FIELD
```

I have added this info here since I was not able to find it anywhere else or found here any option to post it on the appropriate VB forum.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function GetRowDataText(col As Integer) As String
    Try
        Dim dRow As DataRowView=Type(comboBoxName.SelectedItem,DataRowView)
        Return dRow.Row.ItemArray(col)            
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).